# using array names in tcl to get the indices matching regexp

Tags: arrays, tcl

Following array is set in tcl

```
db(PR,)       =
db(PR,132754) = 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
db(PR,144917) = 2 3 28 29
db(PR,83055)  = 4 30
```

I want all the array indices except db(PR,) since it has nothing after comma

I tried:

```
array names db -regexp PR,\d+
```

but it gives no output
and 
array names db -regexp PR,*
PR,144917 PR,132754 PR, PR,83055

return unwanted PR, index

So how can i eliminate that array index from getting in array names output?

Comment: Is this the best solution? regexp -all -inline {PR,\d+} [array names db -regexp PR,\d*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
array names db -regexp PR,.+
```

?

Resp.: If there are always digits after the comma (except for db(PR,)) you should escape the backslash

```
array names db -regexp PR,\\d+
```

or do

```
array names db -regexp PR,\[0-9]+
```

Answer (score 3):

If the criterion is simply "must be something after the comma", it can be as simple as

```
array names db -regexp ,. 
array names db -glob *,?*  ;# alternative
```